# strcpy giving seg fault

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to create an array of strings the user inputs through standard input and having trouble with strcpy. Let's just say the user inputs one string and I want to put it at index 0 of my strings array, this is what I'm doing

```
// Assuming the user won't input anymore than 100 characters
char input[100];
char temp[100];
char buffer[100];
char *array_of_strings[1];

if(fgets(buffer, 100, stdin) != NULL){
sscanf(buffer, "%s", temp);
strcpy(array_of_strings[0], temp);
}
```

I get a segmentation fault as soon as I do the strcpy and I can't figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_of_strings` is an array whose single element is a `char*` pointer. A `char*` *may* point to a string, but you have to allocate memory to contain that string somehow.

```
strcpy(array_of_strings[0], temp);
```

`array_of_strings[0]` is an *uninitialized* pointer. Passing it as the first argument to `strcpy()` has undefined behavior. It will likely (try to) clobber whatever chunk of memory its garbage value happens to point to -- or, if you're lucky, your memory management system will catch the error and kill your program.

One way around this would be to define `array_of_strings` as an array of arrays, rather than as an array of pointers:

```
char array_of_strings[1][100];
```

Another would be to use `malloc` to allocate space:

```
char *array_of_strings[1];
array_of_strings[0] = malloc(100);
if (array_of_strings[0] == NULL) {
    /* allocation failed take some corrective action */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_of_strings[0]` is a pointer, not an array. So, either you use [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) to dynamically allocate memory and use `array_of_strings[0]` as an array or you can't copy a string into it.